# Tail only first few character of a line

Tags: linux, bash, substring, tail

I have a text log of computation which contains a line for each iteration.
We track the computation with

```
tail -f log.txt
```

But the lines of log file are **very** long and the tail output is unreadable.

I've tried this

```
tail -f log.txt | head -c 50
```

but it shows only beginning of the first line, but not lines which are produced after.

How can I dynamically display only first 50 characters of newly added line to the log file?

Thank you

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use cut:

```
tail -f log.txt | cut -b 1-50
```

Comment: just remember that output will be buffered, so you may have to wait a while before anything is shown

Answer (score 3):

This is working for me:

```
tail -f log.txt | awk '{print substr ($0, 0, 50)}'
```